# How to disable checkbox after limit is reached in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

The following code works to limit to 2 checkboxes but the checkbox is [disabled] completely and prevents the (click) event from firing and I lose the ability to uncheck.

What would be a solution?

This is my HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" name="{{i}}" #name="ngModel" [disabled]="checkboxCurrent == checkboxLimit" (click)="checkboxCheck(name)" ngModel>
</div>
```

This is the TS:

```
checkboxCurrent: number = 0;
checkboxLimit: number = 2;
checkboxDisabled: boolean = false;

checkboxCheck(name) {
  if (name.value != true) {
    this.checkboxCurrent ++;
    if (this.checkboxCurrent == this.checkboxLimit) {
      this.checkboxDisabled = true;
    } else {
      this.checkboxDisabled = false;
    }
  } else {
    this.checkboxCurrent --;
  }
}
```

Comment: In disable condition also check that checkbox is unchecked. So, your checked checkbox won't get disabled.

Comment: What's the point of disable then? I can't understand..

Answer (score 0):

write a small function for disable  like this

```
[disable]="getDisabledStatus(name)"
```

the function would do below :

```
getDisabledStatus(name):boolean  {
  if ( (name.value && checkboxCurrent == checkboxLimit) 
       || (checkboxCurrent != checkboxLimit) ) {
     return false;
  }else  {
   return true;
  }
}
```